# Why isn't the submit event received when submitting a comment via pressing the enter key when the listener uses addEventListener and not onsubmit?

Tags: support, comments

I'm writing a userscript and want to attach an event listener to run when a comment is submitted. I was surprised that I couldn't receive the `submit` event when the form is submitted via pressing the enter key and the event listener is registered to the form element via `addEventListener` instead of `.onsubmit = (ev) => ...` (I can receive the event using `.onsubmit = (ev) => ...`, but I'd much prefer not to for the reasons @Makyen has explained in the comments).

Why does this happen?

The minimal reproducible example: Get the comment form element (`.comment-form > form`), and give it an event listener for the `submit` event like: `commentForm.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => { console.log("submit event received"); })`. Then type a comment and submit it by pressing the enter key. Observe that the event is not received by the listener. Then try the same thing but use `commentForm.onsubmit = <...>`.

Note: I'm currently working around this by adding a second event listener listening to keyboard events.

Comment: You should almost *never* use [event handler properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_handler_properties), like the `.onsubmit = (ev) => ...` example you've shown, because there can only ever be one such handler, which makes it *really* easy to introduce bugs. Basically, you should only use them when the fact that there can be only one handler is an intentionally used feature (e.g. you want to be able to remove the event handler without knowing which function is currently handling such events).

Comment: @Makyen Yep. I'm very aware of that. That's why I'm trying to use `addEventListener` instead of `onsubmit`.

Comment: Then the issue is very likely to be that event propagation is being stopped prior to your handler receiving it. To solve that, you would need to install your handler earlier in the event propagation chain. Usually, this can be accomplished by installing it in the capturing phase, with perhaps the need to install it on an element higher in the DOM.

Comment: @Makyen I had the handler placed on the `form` element using `{capture:true}`. I'll try what you said about placing the listener higher up in the hierarchy. I think that could work.

Comment: Alternately, look at SE's code and see what they are doing to handle the event (or precursor events) and preventing it from propagating and/or preventing that event from firing.